# Compare function of string class not working as expected

Tags: c++, class, if-statement, input, string-comparison

I want to search professors based on their names. So i have to compare the name i am entering to the professor name. I tried debugging, what's happening is that its not going into the if(compare) statement. And I can't figure out why. Its a quite big code so I'm just including a part of it. "professors" is a vector of type Professor which is class.

```
        void RecruitProfessor()
        {
            Professor prof = Professor();

            string college,name,role,subject;
            cout<<"Enter the College Name: ";
            fflush(stdin);
            getline(cin, college);
            cout<<"Enter the Professor Name: ";
            getline(cin, name);
            fflush(stdin);
            cout<<"Enter the Professor Role: ";
            getline(cin, role);
            fflush(stdin);
            cout<<"Enter the Professor Subject: ";
            getline(cin, subject);
            fflush(stdin);


            prof.setCollegeName(college);
            prof.setProfessorName(name);
            prof.setProfessorRole(role);
            prof.setProfessorSubject(subject);
            professors.push_back(prof);
        }

        void DisplayProfessorInfo()
        {
            bool returnToMainMenu = false;
            while(!returnToMainMenu)
            {
                cout<<"1. Fetch the details of all the professors \n";
                cout<<"2. Fetch the details of professors by Name \n";
                cout<<"3. Fetch the details of professors by Role \n";
                cout<<"4. Fetch the details of professors by Subject \n";
                cout<<"5. Fetch the details of professors by Colleges \n";
                cout<<"6. Return to main menu \n";

                Professor prof = Professor();
                int choice;
                cout<<"Please enter your choice:\n";
                choice = getInt();
                switch(choice)
                {
                    case 1:
                    {
                        if(professors.size()==0)
                        {
                            cout<<"\n\nNo professors found!\n\n";
                            returnToMainMenu = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            for(Professor i:professors)
                            {
                                //cout << i.getProfessorCollege() << endl;
                                cout<<"Professor College: " + i.getProfessorCollege() + "\n";
                                cout<<"Professor Name: " + i.getProfessorName() + "\n";
                                cout<<"Professor Role: " + i.getProfessorRole() + "\n";
                                cout<<"Professor Subject: " + i.getProfessorSubject() + "\n";
                                cout<<"\n\n";
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    case 2:
                    {
                        string name;
                        if(professors.size()==0)
                        {
                            cout<<"\n\nNo professors sfound!\n\n";
                            returnToMainMenu = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            getline(cin, name);
                            fflush(stdin);
                            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
                            //cout<<name;
                            for(Professor i:professors)
                            {
                                if((name.compare(i.getProfessorName()))==0)
                                {
                                    cout<<"Professor College: " + i.getProfessorCollege() + "\n";
                                    cout<<"Professor Name: " + i.getProfessorName() + "\n";
                                    cout<<"Professor Role: " + i.getProfessorRole() + "\n";
                                    cout<<"Professor Subject: " + i.getProfessorSubject() + "\n";
                                    cout<<"\n\n";
                                }
                                else{continue;}
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    }
```

Comment: First of all, if you don't need a metric between the strings, you can compare them with the good old `==`, that one is perfectly fine when you work with `std::string` (it would not be if you'd work with `char*`). Second, have you used a debugger? Set yourself some breakpoints at relevant positions, check where it enters conditions different that it is supposed to. Then take a breakpoint just before that and look at the current variable states. Or, if you can't use debuggers, put prints in your code, like "variable x has value y" and "am at postion z in the code".

Answer (score 0):

(Sry I cannot comment)

Your name comparison seems fine, so maybe you could add:

```
cout << "'" << name << "' vs '" << i.name << "' is " << name.compare(i.name) << endl;
```

Otherwise a smaller full example would help (e.g. drop how you fill from stdin and just use fixed values, drop the loop, drop the switch, etc). Test after each simplification, this way you may already find what was causing the problems.

Answer (score 0):

Some possible portions of error, along with unnecessary code:

- Instead of `choice = getInt();`, simply use `cin>>choice`;
- There's no need for using such code:

```
getline(cin, name);
fflush(stdin);
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

when your not even taking another string or line of input after using the `getline()` above. (following calls to a `cout`)

Instead use `cin>>name`. Initially your code with these lines included were not working when I tried it on an online compiler. But it works now, following the removal of those with a simple `std::cin`.

I made a small reproducible example on the basis of your code and it works fine:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Professor 
{   public:
    std::string name;
    std::string getName()
    { return name; }
};

int main() 
{ std::vector<Professor> professors;
  Professor a,b,c;
  a.name = "eerorika"; b.name = "S.S.Anne" ; c.name = "walnut";
  professors.push_back(a);
  professors.push_back(b);
  professors.push_back(c);
  int choice; 
  std::cin>>choice;
  switch(choice)
  {
    case 1:
    {  std::string profname;
       std::cin>>profname;
       if(professors.size()!=0)
       for(Professor i:professors)
         if(profname.compare(i.getName())==0)
           std::cout<<"Professor name = "<<i.getName()<<"\n";
        break;   
    }
    case 2:
    {  std::cout<<"Mystical";
       break;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```